# Clearing the "old" scrollback buffer

Tags: linux, console, scrolling

This might seem to be a duplicate question but it isn't.

I know that I can use `printf "\033f"` to clear the scrollback buffer of the "current" session but that doesn't work for old sessions.

My problem is I access several VM's through XVP viewer (a java web browser based VNC) and if I don't make a effort to clear the screen before logging out every time everything can be viewed by scrolling the screen.

Please suggest a way to clear this old scrollback buffer.

PS: Rebooting clears it but I can't do that on production VMs

Comment: Does the 'switch to a different virtual console and then back' trick work?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than skip several lines, the Linux kernel has since (at least 2011) supported a control sequence which will clear the scrollback:

```
printf '\033[3J'
```

It is mentioned in the ncurses changes for [July 16, 2011](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20110716):

```
    + add E3 extended capability to linux-basic (Miroslav Lichvar)
    + add linux2.2, linux2.6, linux3.0 entries to give context for E3 -TD
```

and explained in the [terminal database](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-linux3_0):

```
# The 3.0 kernel adds support for clearing scrollback buffer (capability E3).
# It is the same as xterm's erase-saved-lines feature.
linux3.0|linux 3.0 kernels,
        E3=\E[3J, use=linux2.6,
```

That came up in the context of a bug report where it was noted that a feature added to xterm in June 1999 would be useful for improving security of applications on the Linux console.

Subsequently (in [2013](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/NEWS.html#t20130622)), the `E3` feature was added to the `clear` utility, so that (depending on which terminal description is used) the utility would clear the scrollback.  The comment about *Ctrl+l* refers to a bash shortcut which may hardcode the same escape sequence (since the terminal database does not tie the `clear` (or `ed`) and `E3` capabilities together).

Further reading:

- [Red Hat Bug 815790: [RFE-privacy] clear the console](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=815790)
- [Red Hat Bug 683733: Content above dimensions of cleared display is still visible for locked screen session](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=683733)

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this. Basically the console screen has 510 lines of buffer (in my case), so `echo`ing 511 times fills all those lines clearing the old data.

I'm using `echo` inside a `for` loop

```
for i in {0..510}
 do
    echo
 done
```

On old bash prompts `seq` can be used.

```
for i in `seq 0 510`
 do
    echo
 done
```

Comment: Or use Ctrl+l combination :)